# how to get values from vector in JSP

Tags: jsp

I am developing a website in which it has searching option. after searching from database, it listed certain data in a jsp page and all the data from database are stored in vector and I am displaying those data with the for each.

For each data listed in the page has one submit button. When I click button I need the particular value corressponding to the submit button. And pass it to the servlet.

I finished up to searching data and display..my problem is, I don't know how to get the value of the particular submit button and pass it to the servlet.

I need one more help sir, I have to pass the value to the javascript or to keep the value in hidden for some time.. Below I give my code so that you can understand easily
.JSP coding:

```
Mobile form
input type="hidden" name="id_city" value="${v.city}" 
input type="submit" class="send" id="mobileid"  name="mobile" value=""  onclick="openbox('Get information by SMS/Email', 0)"/ 
 /form 
 html 
 body form action="servlet"/ 
/body 
 input type="text" name="mobile"/ 
 input type="submit" value="sendsms" 
 /form 
 /html (while giving tag its not accepting as characters dont mistake me)
```

openbox() is a javascript function to display a html page which is in same page with some format like the previous page has to remain and html page should appear on the previous page like a box in that it has fields textbox and submit button..

My problem is I have to take the value from the hidden value in jsp page to the servlet after the submit button is clicked.. since the hidden value is in form if I click the submit button which is in upper html code. It reload the page so the open box is not appearing.. where i have to change the code to get the openbox window after clicking sendsms button it need to take the hiddenvalues along with the text box value to servlet. please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Put each item in its own form with a hidden input element wherein you pass the item ID.

E.g.

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
    <form action="view">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${item.id}">
        <input type="submit" value="view">
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

The item ID will be available in the servlet as follows:

```
Long id = Long.valueOf(request.getParameter("id"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..i have doubt in this.. i am displaying the content in a for each loop.. so it has 3 fields and one submit button for each data..In a page it has 3 data with corresponding fields and submit button.. if i give like above coding it will take all the data in the jsp page.. but i need to take the particular fields of its corresponding submit button is clicked and that particular data has to send to servlet..plz help me..

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having with it.

Comment: ok let me explain in detail..After searching data from database,it display the content using jstl in a page. the each data contain fields like city,phone number etc and one submit button. now the page contains more than one data for ex 3 data and each data contains fields like phone number,city and one submit button. If the user pressed the particular submit button i need to pass the corresponding value of fields (city,phone  number) which is in jstl variable to the servlet. plz reply its very urgent..

Comment: Yes I understand the requirement, but I don't understand the problem you have with it. At what point are you stucking?

Comment: i am stucking in getting the value of the fields for the particular submit button..i used hidden values to reterive the data but its returns the first data for the all submit buttons.. i dont know how to reterive values for each submit button is pressed..

Comment: Put each button in its own `<form>`, exactly as in my answer. The `<form>` should be inside `<c:forEach>`, not outside.

Comment: I need one more help sir, i have to pass the value to the javascript or to keep the value in hidden for some time..   I explained problem with my code in my question..